# Cucumber @After scenario implementation in serenity-bdd

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, serenity-bdd

Recently i have started using Serenity BDD [Earlier i was using Cucumber with Java] and having problem in implementing 
Cucumber @After in Serenity BDD.

I have few steps that needs to be executed for every scenario irrespective of pass/fail of the scenario in serenity. I know how to achieve the same in cucumber java but has no idea in serenity.

In Cucumber

```
@After
public void endScenario(Scenario scenarioResult){
 //Steps
}
```

Please help me how can i achieve the same in serenity

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the endScenario method´s package to the ***glue*** in your CucumberOptions

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = { ... },
    plugin = { ... },
    glue = {"...", "com.company.project.your.package"}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty similar.

Here is an example of if you wanted to perform an @After hook for every scenario with that tag "@Test"

```
@After(value = "@Test")
public void after() {
    //do something
}
```

make sure you use the correct import for cucumber and not junit's after...

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;
```

Then make sure you add the @Test tag above any scenarios you want this to apply to. If you place a tag above the Feature line in your feature file right at the top, it will apply to all scenarios in that feature.

Hope that helps a bit.